# Slack api to know conversation between two users being an admin

Tags: javascript, api, slack

I have successfully made an app to make user conversation but I want know if being an admin I can know all the conversation between my team members.
[Offical Website link](https://api.slack.com/methods)  has helped me a lot but not able to get the api to know whole conversation being a team admin.

Answer (score 1):

> You’d need to create a Slack app and have the user which DM’s you’d
>   like to have access to authenticate against it. This will grant you an
>   access token that you can then use to call the appropriate API
>   endpoints to retrieve these messages.
>
> The im.list method (https://api.slack.com/methods/im.list) returns a
>   list of the calling users DM conversations
>   (https://api.slack.com/types/im - An IM object contains information
>   about a direct message channel).
>
> The im.history method (https://api.slack.com/methods/im.history)
>   returns either a portion or entire history of the direct message
>   channel, depending on the arguments passed when making the call.
>
> To clarify, authorization is on a per user basis. There is no master
>   token that will allow access to all DM’s for an entire team. This is
>   expected behaviour and by design for security and privacy.

The above is the response from Slack Team member.It clearly states that you cannot do so as it will nullify the Slack's privacy policy.